# setting all active quotes to inactive , for the logged user

Tags: magento-community, shopping-cart, quote, save, mini-cart

This is the code I use, which is not working, in order to make all of active quotes for the logged user to inactive, but it keeps taking only one quote.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote');
$quoteID = $quote->getId();

while ($quoteID)
{

    // Set inactive 
    $quote->setIsActive(0);
    $quote->save();

    // find next inactive quote <- NOT WORKING! $quoteID STAYS THE SAME!
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote');
    $quoteID = $quote->getId();

}
```

Comment: No idea what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton()` returns always the same instance, so at no point in your script, another quote is loaded.

Comment: fschmengler, I need to set all quotes to not active. I have a bug caused by one magento module which I must use which create a damaged quote (quote with NULL product_id). when I log to system ant there's NULL product_id in my quote. It causes error. when I set quotes to not active all is ok. I want to make quotes not active by code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following -:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
  $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection');
  $collection->getSelect()->where('(is_active=1 and customer_id='.$customer->getId().')');
  foreach($collection as $col){
      $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($col->getId());
      $quote->setIsActive(0);
      $quote->save();
  } //foreach
}//If clause
```

Hope it helps

Cheers
S

Comment: Hi thank you very much loops great on all of the quotes!
But still some problem. It looks like it works only when $quote->save(); is commented out. Do you have any idea why ?